# "Error 502 Bad Gateway - Host Error" After Droplet Reboot

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I had to reset my root password to regain access to my account. This caused the Droplet to shut down and restart. After the restart, I am unable to access the website which is hosted on my DigitalOcean droplet.

While examining the log file `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I found the following error:

`[error] 999#999: *77 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Please suggest possible steps to get my site up and running.

Comment: is nginx on docker? or is it installed as deb?

Comment: `upstream` means that nginx will connect to some other service. Are you using php? If yes: Is php-fpm running and is the IP/Socket correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solved now.
The javascript file inside the website folder did not start automatically after reboot, need to manually start it using
`pm2 start [app_name].js`

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I checked the pm2 list, it seemed processes were running.
So I just reloaded them using command.

```
pm2 reload < process name >
```

Everything were okay, but in fact staging and production app still threw 502 bad gateway.

So I stopped processes and restarted them, and then everything were really worked.

```
pm2 stop < process name >
pm2 restart < process name >
```

I think after restarting the droplet, need to drop or stop the process and then restart that.